# Is there a mini series that tells Ryoma's experience in the U.S. Open (Prince of Tennis)?

Tags: prince-of-tennis

I just finished watching *Prince of Tennis* and I'm about to start *Prince of Tennis: the National Tournament*, but it goes directly to Nationals without telling us what happened with Ryoma in the U.S. Open.

I want to know if there is a mini series about that period because I really want to know what happened.

Comment: Please don't ask about whether there **will be** something - there is no way we will know.

Comment: Well, maybe someone heard or read about a mini series, that's why I was asking

Comment: This is not cannon.  Just a filler. In fact this has been noted to clash with some cannon timeline elements when overlapped.  Just pretend it didn't happen.

Comment: really? oh, but I got so exited :(